# Check if a Memory Buffer Contain Structured Storage File Data

Tags: c++, file, com, ole, structured-storage

I need to check if a in memory buffer BYTE* lpBuf contain data of a stucture storage file data.

Currently I save the buffer data into a temp file, then use StgOpenStorage to open the file. If the open succeeds, then the file is a structured storage file, otherwise it is not.

```
CFile File;

if (File.Open(_T("E:\\Myfile.dat"), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeRead)
{
  File.Write(lpBuf, uBufSize);
  File.Close();
}

LPSTORAGE lpStorageFile = NULL;

HRESULT hr = StgOpenStorage(_T("E:\\Myfile.dat"), NULL, STGM_TRANSACTED | STGM_READ | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, NULL, 0, &lpStorageFile);

return SUCCEED(hr);
```

Is there any easy way to do the task?

Thanks

Comment: You would favor StgIsStorageFile() to do this test, avoids the leak.  Avoid the file with StgIsStorageILockBytes(), created with CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal().

Comment: My data is stored in BYTE* lpBuf, not in hGlobal created by GlobalAlloc. In such a case, CreateLockBytesOnHGlobal() seems to not workable for the case?